# Deadlock in oracle database (imported by datapump) on the row with the same primary key (insert and select for update)

Tags: oracle, deadlock

This problem happens ONLY with the database user, which was imported by datapump. The problem is NOT present with the original database user.

I am getting deadlock in oracle 11.2.0.3 version where the current sqls of two transactions participating in deadlock are as follows :

```
 SELECT /*AApaAA*/ objectid FROM T_DS_0 WHERE objectid = :1 FOR UPDATE

 insert /*AApaAA*/ into T_DS_0(OBJECTID) values (:1 )
```

Both bind variables are 'AApaAA' and it is also primary key. It looks like deadlock on single resource.

There are foreign keys (on delete cascade) pointing to that primary key and they are indexed.

The deadlock graph is as follows :

```
            ---------Blocker(s)-------- ---------Waiter(s)---------
 Resource Name      process session holds waits  process session holds waits
 TX-000c000f-00000322    49 102     X                  46    587          X
 TX-00070011-00000da4    46 587     X                  49    102          S
```

It is not clear to me how the deadlock could happen at the single resource. It is true that the insert does not lock the row but the constraint which is probably a different resource, so that the deadlock could theoretically be possible if 1st transaction would perform the lock constraint and then lock row and the other one would be in the reverse order but I do not see any way how this could happen. Theoretically there is the child table locking possible (insert causes SX on child tables) but the select for update should not touch the child tables at all.

The full tracefile from oracle is at : https://gist.github.com/milanro/06f9a76a2607a26ac9ba8c91b88639b3

Did anyone experience a similar behavior?

Additional Info : This problem happens only when datapump is used to duplicate the db user. The original schema contains SYS indexes created during creation of Primary Keys. There are further indexes which start with the PRIMARY KEY column. Datapump then does not create the SYS index on the PRIMARY KEY column but uses the indexes starting with the PRIMARY KEY column.

It looks like when I create following database objects :

create table tbl(objectid varchar2(30), a integer, primary key (objectid));

create index idx1 on tbl(objectid,a);

there is 1 table and 2 indexes created. SYS index (OBJECTID) and idx1(OBJECTID,A). The PRIMARY KEY uses the SYS index.

After the datapump si performed, on the imported side only 1 table and 1 index is created, the index is idx1(OBJECTID, A) and that index is used for the PRIMARY KEY.

This happens in my database schema with the table SDMBase. And the deadlocks happen when I use in different transactions the combination of INSERT INTO SDMBase ... and SELECT ... FROM SDMBase ... FOR UPDATE where I use the same OBJECTID. The same code is executed in those transactions and it can be as follows in 1 transaction

```
1.INSERT (objectid1)
2.SELECT FOR UPDATE (objectid1)
3.INSERT (objectid1)
4.SELECT FOR UPDATE (objectid1)
```

...

The deadlocking situation happens on the line 2. and line 3. In my use-case, when these transactions run, the row with objectid1 is already in the database but does not have to be committed yet.

So I suppose that

```
step 1. should wait until objectid1 is commited and then fail and lock nothing
step 2. should lock objectid1 or wait if another transaction already locked it
step 3. should fail immediately and lock nothing
```

...

Apparently the step 1 even if failing, holds lock on PK for some time but only in case, the database is duplicated by datapump.

These deadlocks are rare and not reproducible manually, I suppose that the lock is not held the whole transaction but only very short time.

so it could be as follows :

```
TX1: 1.INSERT (objectid1) (fails and does not lock)
TX1: 2.SELECT (objectid1) (locks SDMBase)
TX2: 1.INSERT (objectid1) (fails but locks PK)
TX1: 3.INSERT (objectid1) (waits on PK)
TX2: 2.SELECT (objectid1) (waits on SDMBase)
```

Even if I create the index in the imported portal as SDMBase(OBJECTID) and let the PRIMARY KEY to use it, and even if I recreate the other index (OBJECTID,...), it still deadlocks. So I suppose that there is some problem with the PK constraint check.

The fix of this problem is to create the SDMBase(OBJECTID), let the PRIMARY KEY use it and then perform the datapump again. The import must be performed in 2 steps, at first one to exclude indexes and at the second one import only indexes

1. exclude=INDEX/INDEX,statistics
2. include=INDEX/INDEX CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY

This problem occurs in both 11.2.0.3 and 12.2.0.1

Comment: Why dou you select for update a row AApaAA that does not exist yet in the table ? It is inserted by the next insert command.Or maybe I am missing something ?

Comment: First transaction inserts the row and starts further threads with their own transactions but they can start at first, when that original row is committed. So at beginning of each TX, there is an insert of the same row in the nested transaction. If the row was committed by the original TX, this command fails which is expected behavior. If it was roll-backed, this insert goes through which is an error. If the original TX was not yet committed, it waits.  Once it passes correctly (fails with UQ violation), we lock that row so that nobody else can work with it. That is the select for update.

Comment: Can you check which object is causing the deadlock?  I think you can find it like this: `select * from dba_objects where object_id = 85986;`.  Maybe the deadlock is happening on an object you're not thinking about - maybe some other related table, a bitmap index, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately this shows T_DS_0.  The other side would be more interesting but it has has 'no row'.  I suppose that there would be PRIMARY KEY index. So the deadlock could happen as we have 2 resources. I only don't know the sequence of commands. seq 1: insert, sfu(select for update), seq2: sfu,insert could not work because if the row exists, insert would fail and should not lock, if it does not exist, sfu would not lock.I do not have delete in place.